# Rename batch file extension after execution

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, file-extension

I was wondering if there is a way to change the file extension of a batch file(.bat) after it's execution. So, for example, I want to execute abc.bat. After the batch file does what it's supposed to do, it renames itself by changing the .bat to .txt Would this be possible??

Comment: What does this have to do with C++, Python, or C?

Answer (score 2):

I just tried. It's pretty simple. At the end of your batch file, add:

```
ren %~dp0\abc.bat abc.txt
```

In this, `%~dp0` indicates the path to your batch file as I mentioned [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2005/01/28/get-directory-path-of-an-executing-batch-file.aspx).

Note it has to be the very last step of execution of the batch file.

Comment: I ended up finding a different method. lol. thanks tho! Much appreciation!

Comment: Care to share that other method?

Comment: You can just rename `%~dpnx0` instead of encoding the batch file name in there as well. And put it in quotes to protect against spaces in the path.

Comment: I use a similar script to delete the BAT file after operation. To archive, I'm using `(goto) 2>nul & ren "%~dpnx0" *.bak` as the last line.